# Android Audio Codec Support

Tags: android, audio, codec

Is there any way to record & edit audio files using ADPCM codec in Android?

Apart from AMR_WB & AMR_NB audio codec; which all other open/standard codec supported in Android?

Answer (score 0):

You should look into Android official Documentation for this apart from that you can support many other formats in your app by compiling [FFmpeg](http://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=ffmpeg%20wiki&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CB0QFjAA&url=http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FFmpeg&ei=c3HwTp_4C8nZrQfU95zYDw&usg=AFQjCNFjDgNGOT2Oei4aDQuh9SA3Iv1uUw&cad=rja) library

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html